# Func A calls Func B and Vice versa (why does it not work) Experimenting

Tags: c++, function

I am just experimenting with C++ and trying to understand the basics of it through this lovely website http://www.learncpp.com/

Now i am just trying my Following CODE:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int trollFuncyA(int x){
    x++;
    cout << "we are In A and x = " << x << endl;
    if (x > 20) return 1 ;
    cout << "we are In a1 and x = " << x << endl;
    int trollFuncyB(x);
    cout << "we are In a2 and x = " << x << endl;
    return 0;
}

int trollFuncyB(int x){
    cout << "we are In B9 and x = " << x << endl;
     x++;
     x =  x + 1;
      cout << "we are In B and x = " << x << endl;
     int  trollFuncyA(x);
      cout << "we are In B2 and x = " << x << endl;
      return 0;
}

int main()
{

    int troll = 0;

   trollFuncyA(troll );

    return 0;
}
```

when I try to run it I run into some issues:

1.) warning: C4189: 'trollFuncyB' : local variable is initialized but not referenced  (how can I solve that or is it unsolvable

2.) I was hoping that int X would add up to 20   but it just run only trollFuncyA just only once until the end of the function, it almost seems that it ignores the trollFuncyB   ..... No matter how silly this program is. is it possible to make this run? **I am Just trying to experiment here and I know about for / while loops .. I just thought this would be able to run as intended**

Regards A newby

Answer (score 3):

```
int trollFuncyB(x);
```

This doesn't call `trollFuncyB`. It declares a local variable named `trollFuncyB` of type `int` and initializes its value to `x`. You get that warning because this local variable is never used.

Call a function like this:

```
trollFuncyB(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

`int trollFuncyB(x);` is equivalent to `int trollFuncyB = x;`.
It is a declaration of a variable of type `int` initialized with `x`.

You should replace it by:

```
int trollFuncyB(int); // declaration of the function (may be done outside of the function)
trollFuncyB(x);       // The call
```